# Release of Divergent: Ascendant

Tags: production, continuity, divergent

Is there any definitive knowledge on whether the 4th Divergent movie (Divergent: Ascendant) is going to be released?  I have heard that it was shelved, and I have also heard that it is going to be released as a TV movie to wrap up the book series (as a part 2 of Allegiant).

**Note:** In response to a comment,

> ... a title's release date or rumors about a specific title or series are **specifically** off-topic for M&TV

I am not after a release date or rumours.  I am after definitive knowledge based on what the movie producers have said in any interviews etc.

Comment: I am skeptical about its future, their third film performed bad and  Shailene Woodley backed out, the television show is not fully finalized I guess.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because a title's release date or rumors about a specific title or series are **specifically** off-topic for M&TV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The movie has officially been cancelled, due to the seriously poor responses from critics and box-office of the third one.

It was announced the follow-up would be as a TV Show to close the story, but Shailene Woodley (actress of Beatrice) quit the project because "she did not sign up for a TV Show."

All in all, both the Movie and the TV Show have been cancelled for now.